# jQuery-Like Way to Find / Select Array of React Elements

Tags: jquery, reactjs, lodash, dom-selection

I created this little function to find children of a specific `type`.

I'd like to be able to select children via property like jQuery, `[name="example"]`. Is there any way to strip the string selector functionality from jQuery to create an object map to feed to something like lodash's `_.find`?

I realize this is a fake solution for selecting / finding / filtering an array but I think it can be really useful. I also know that it won't find deep children, it would just deal with direct root children.

Does this exist within react already?

```
function containsElement (element, children) {
  var result = []
  element = _.flatten([element])
  if (React.isValidElement(children) && !_.isArray(children)) {
    var contains = _.contains(element, children.type)
    if (contains) return children
    return false
  } else if (!React.isValidElement(children) && !_.isArray(children)) {
    return false
  }
  children.forEach(function (child) {
    var isElm = React.isValidElement(child)
    var contains = _.contains(element, child.type)
    if (isElm && contains) {
      result.push(child)
    }
  })
  if (!result.length) return false
  return result
}
```

Comment: If you're using a modern browser, the majority of the selector power in jQuery is available natively using `document.querySelectorAll` which uses the css selector engine. You could also instead use [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is what jQuery's selector engine is built upon.

Comment: But I want to supply the HTML / elements as in `this.props.children`.

Comment: @KevinB +1 for mentioning Sizzle.  ThomasReggi do check out Sizzle, it may well be the answer to your question.

Comment: Just tried this `Sizzle.matches('tr', this.props.children)` didn't work. Returning empty array. Could it be because it's not a real DOM element array?

Comment: What exactly is `children`? .matches is equivalent to jQuery's `.filter` method in that it will filter the top level dom nodes in the collection by the selector, it won't look at anything below the top level in the collection.

Comment: @KevinB jQuery + Sizzle both don't work http://jsbin.com/rofulo/4/edit?js,output

Comment: To me it looks like your'e not doing a selector-type selction at all, but instead are trying to see if nodes x y and z are found within collection a, which is a whole nother beast.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah I had a feeling the solution needs to be React-specific. This is why I mentioned `_.find` because what I want is to filter an array of react elements with classic jQuery string selectors but not select from the DOM.

Comment: yeah, sizzle with selectors won't work on non-dom nodes.

Comment: Why would you need such a function when working with React? It's probably not helpful to use a "jquery" tag when asking a React question because the imperative DOM manipulation of jQuery doesn't mix well with React's declarative approach. A "how to do x?" question with just a "reactjs" tag might yield an enlightening answer.

Comment: @RickJolly I included the jQuery tag because we're all used to the way jQuery allows us to specifically filter and select DOM Elements. I want that same functionality for React. Why? Because I'd like to select all of a specific type of Node / check if a specific node(s) exist and how many there are.

Comment: And when are you planning to use this? When the component has mounted? How could you know your child nodes has mounted too? React introduces another way of thinking about DOM and timing, bringing jQuery DOM traversing back into the mix would be confusing IMO.

Comment: @David It's not traversing! `this.props.children` is a simple array of objects that aren't attached to the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple version of what I want that only supports element type.

```
selectElements('div, span', this.props.children)
```

Ideally I can do this and it would get all `divs` with the `name` `prop` set to `hello`.

```
selectElements('div[name="hello"]', this.props.children)
```

Here's full example, [(jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/zigebo/9/edit?js,output).

```
var selectElements = function (selectorString, reactElements) {
  var selectors = selectorString.split(',')
  selectors = _.map(selectors, function (item) {
    return item.replace(/^\s+|\s$/, '')
  })
  return _.filter(reactElements, function (reactElement) {
    return _.contains(selectors, reactElement.type)
  })
}

var OnlyElements = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'OnlyElements',
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      children: this.props.children
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.setState({
      children: selectElements(this.props.allow, this.props.children)
    })
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Test = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Test',
  render: function () {
    return (
      <OnlyElements allow='div'>
        <span>Alpha</span>
        <div>Beta</div>
        <span>Gamma</span>
      </OnlyElements>
    )
  }
})

React.render(<Test/>, document.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little open-source library called [react-query](https://github.com/elierotenberg/react-query) that does exactly that.

*edit: The react-query repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.*

Comment: It seems react-query is abandoned, this other lib should do the trick: [teaspoon](https://github.com/jquense/teaspoon)

Comment: @Zaninotto teaspoon has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only. would you share with us what do you use currently?